# How do I load large number of small CSV files from s3 to redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have large number of CSV files (~12k) which are small (~250 records each). I want to load them to redshift cluster of size 3 in the same region, but it's taking a really long time.

The query I used in SQL Workbench/J is :

```
copy gsod from 's3://[path to folder]' access_key_id '******' secret_access_key '******' delimiter ',' BLANKSASNULL emptyasnull IGNOREHEADER 1 maxerror as 100000;
```

The query works in seconds if I use single file. But What's the best way to load all of them as quickly as possible ?

I have tried loading the files from s3 from the same region of the cluster.

```
copy gsod from 's3://[path to folder]' access_key_id '******' secret_access_key '******' delimiter ',' BLANKSASNULL emptyasnull IGNOREHEADER 1 maxerror as 100000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go for `manifest` file option. It will do really fast.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html

```
  {
"entries": [
{"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
{"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true},
{"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
{"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true}
]}
```

This will do the `copy` in parallel and instead of processing files one by one, it will load all the files in single attempt.

```
copy customer from 's3://mybucket/your-manifest-file' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole' manifest;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll generate the manifest file from the CSV and then try.

Comment: Worked like a charm !

Comment: @SuhaibAhmed would you mind accepting this as a correct answer?

Comment: @RedBoy do you think that a copy command from s3 - with multiple files in a folder - isn't parallelised without a manifest? - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-multiple-files.html

Comment: @JonScott I'm trying to read my answer again, not able to understand, `where did I say files from folder isn't parallelized`, could you please point out? I just said, menifest will sure make it in parallel, and its also best practice.

Comment: you say "Go for menifest file option. It will do really fast." and "This will do the copy in parallel and instead of processing files one by one, it will load all the files in single attempt." otherwise - why is manifest faster according to your answer?

Comment: I think the key thing here is that it's possible to load multiple files in parallel (and therefore more quickly), rather than one at a time - which is how the OP is doing it in the question. This can be achieved using a manifest file, although it's also possible to specify an S3 object prefix instead of a full filename and that will also cause all files with the same prefix to be processed.